# React application rendering in local but build fails on remote

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, package.json

I am facing the following error:

```
'Switch' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Switch' is not a valid JSX element.
      The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
       Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/usr/src/app/client/node_modules/@types/react-transition-group/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
         Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
          Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.  TS2786
```

I have not changed any version. And also not modify the code of my app. 5 days ago this started to not compile in my remote server. I create the images on a alpine:node docker with version 14.17.4

Can someone provide some insight on where is the error here?

Dependencies versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^4.0.0-alpha.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/openpgp": "^4.4.14",
    "@types/truncate-middle": "^1.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "bottleneck": "^2.19.5",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "file-selector": "^0.2.2",
    "form-data": "^3.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "formik-material-ui": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "formik-material-ui-lab": "0.0.5",
    "formik-material-ui-pickers": "0.0.8",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "3.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "openpgp": "^4.4.5",
    "promise.allsettled": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.1.2",
    "react-ga": "^2.7.0",
    "react-joyride": "^2.3.0",
    "react-kawaii": "^0.16.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-scrollable-feed": "^1.1.2",
    "react-snowfall": "1.0.2",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "trace-error": "^1.0.3",
    "truncate-middle": "^1.0.6",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "uuid": "^8.1.0",
    "yup": "^0.29.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.155",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.59",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.36",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-kawaii": "^0.11.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.3"
  }
```

Could it be that the dependencie React version of react-transition-group is different than the normal one? It doesn't make sense for me that this compiles in local and not in remote.

Comment: This was a problem caused by some dependencies installing last react version and main react version on the project.